# Jasypt encryption stops working after upgrade to JDK 7u261

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jasypt

We recently upgraded to JDK 7u261 from JDK 7u251 as the new release was available to Java SE support customers on April 15, 2020. The Jasypt encryption stopped working after this Java version upgrade. I receive the following error message;

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:773)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:566)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:718)
    at org.jasypt.properties.PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.java:72)
    at org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.convertPropertyValue(EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperty(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperties(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5662)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1007)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1296)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2038)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.NormalizerDataReader.<clinit>(NormalizerDataReader.java:300)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.NormalizerImpl.<init>(NormalizerImpl.java:288)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.NormalizerImpl.<clinit>(NormalizerImpl.java:35)
    at com.ibm.icu.text.Normalizer$Mode.normalize(Normalizer.java:188)
    at com.ibm.icu.text.Normalizer.normalize(Normalizer.java:1177)
    at com.ibm.icu.text.Normalizer.normalize(Normalizer.java:1146)
    at org.jasypt.normalization.Normalizer.normalizeWithIcu4j(Normalizer.java:205)
    at org.jasypt.normalization.Normalizer.normalizeToNfc(Normalizer.java:129)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:718)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version number: Version number may be negative or greater than 255
    at com.ibm.icu.util.VersionInfo.getInstance(VersionInfo.java:188)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.getInstanceLenient(ICUDebug.java:65)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUDebug.<clinit>(ICUDebug.java:69)
    ... 35 more
```

The code used in the applicationContext.xml is as follows;

```
<bean id="encryptorConfig" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
      <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
      <property name="passwordEnvName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
</bean>

<bean id="encryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="config" ref="encryptorConfig" />
</bean> 

<bean class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg ref="encryptor" />

      <property name="locations">
           <list>
               <value>/WEB-INF/spring.properties</value>

           </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding a more recent icu4j dependency.  See also the following bug report in the Jasypt project: "[Encryption stops working after upgrade to Java™ SE Development Kit 7, Update 261 (JDK 7u261)](https://github.com/jasypt/jasypt/issues/33)".

The mentioned bug fix updated to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    <version>67.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The problem I was facing with java 8 as well, upgrading icu dependency solved my issue.